# Login button works with firefox but not with phantomjs

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a login form submission button that looks like this:

```
<input type="button" name="BUTTON1" value="Login" title="Login" class="Bottone1" onclick="if( gx.evt.jsEvent(this)) {gx.evt.execEvt('EENTER.',this);} else return false;" onfocus="gx.evt.onfocus(this, 26,'',false,'',0)">
```

In my ruby script using watir-webdriver and firefox backend this code works fine:

```
browser.button(:name => "BUTTON1").click
```

Unfortunately if I switch to phantomjs backend nothing happens using this code and the screenshot shows me that I'm stuck in the same page.

===
UPDATE:

It looks like the button was triggered but the redirect didn't work. Actually, if after clicking the button I manually go to the desired page it lets me in, so the form is submitted.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but you could try using the [`fire_event`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#fire_event-instance_method) method.  For example:  `browser.button(:name => "BUTTON1").fire_event :onclick`.

Comment: @orde, thanks but same result as before

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why exactly, but phantomjs was a bit buggy for me as well... the same issue... I boiled it to 2 patterns:

1:. Timing issue, you need to add sleeps prior to clicking to give time for the element/page to load (even visible/load checks would fail on me)

2:. .click action for some reason wouldn't trigger the event... I had to add something like the below to workaround:

```
3.times do 
  element.visible? ? element.click : break
end
```

last case scenario you could try something similar as the suggestion in your original comment:

```
element.trigger('click')...
```